# d3.js Cannot read property 'length' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, nvd3.js

i would like to use this [graph](http://nvd3.org/examples/cumulativeLine.html)
with this [JSON](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=c2518249260b71b1ff132bb20f54740e)  but i got the "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using exact same code with the your JSON file, change all the properties named "`value`" to "`values`" in your file.

This error usually tells that expected property of data(or DOM) is absent. Here the code expects the property "`values`" which is not defined in your file, hence it can't read the '`length`' of "`values`".